# Prompt message before git pull

Tags: git

Background: I pulled a new version of an application and when I tried to launch it, it crashed. After a while investigating the issue I found out my it was some missing dependencies application needs now.

I'm wondering if there is some functionality in `git` so that when you `push`a new version, you can add some message that other people will see when they run `git pull`. So for example, when I ran `git pull`, a message telling me that there a some dependencies that must be installed for this version.

I'm not interested in fetch the README before every pull to see if there is anything new, but something "integrated" in the `git` workflow. For example, like `apt-get` when there is some major change, that you get a prompt telling you what changed and you need to actually press `q` to get out of that message.

A workmate told me maybe it was possible using some kind of hook, but he wasn't sure how to do it.

Comment: There is no such facility, because `git` is a source-control tool, not a software distribution mechanism.  Things like dependencies or warning message should be handled as part of your build and installation scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of, but you don't want to go down this road.

You can [write a hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks/2.8.0), specifically the `post-merge` hook, but ***hooks are not copied when you clone a repository***; everyone who cloned your repo would have to take the extra step to install the necessary hooks.  [You can put hooks on the server/upstream side](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-An-Example-Git-Enforced-Policy#_an_example_git_enforced_policy), but that can only enforce policy about pushing upstream.

A somewhat better option is to add the dependencies as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) and then build them as part of your build process.  This is a good idea when those submodules are part of your project, like common code you might have split out into its own repository.

This is a bad idea when they're someone else's code because it circumvents the normal package installation process (`apt-get` and the like) and now users have multiple versions of the code.  It also means they have to build a lot more rather than installing from binaries.

---

[As @larsks pointed out int he comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340468/prompt-message-before-git-pull#comment60303377_36340468), Git is not a release manager, nor is it a build tool, nor an installation tool, nor a dependency manager. You can try to coerce it into being those, but it won't do a very good job.

Instead, you need a build tool with a dependency manager.  These are usually language dependent.